# Filling blank values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I created a 2D array(called `names`) to store string values. Initially, I assign all the elements in the array to blanks.
I do this by having a variable that stores the maximum rows and iterate through the array filling its elements with blanks.

```
public class Untitled
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int maxRows = 10 ;

        String names[][] = new String[maxRows][2] ;

        int y = 0 ;
        while(y <= maxRows)
        {
            int x = 0 ;
            while (index < 2)
            {
                names[y][x] = " " ;
                index++ ;               
            }

            counter++ ;
        }       
    }
}
```

However, once the code is compiled and run, I get an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException : 10"

Comment: Replace `<= maxRows` with `< maxRows`. The highest index is 9, since arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: You're never updating the ```x``` or ```y``` value that actually traverse the matrix.

Comment: If you could explain why did you have `while(index  < 2)` and not `while( index <= 2)` you have answered yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: The code as posted here does not cause the error you claim: https://repl.it/@codeguru/BoilingCurlyInterfacestandard#Main.java. There is a mismatch in variable usage. You have `int y = 0` and `y <= maxRows`, but later `counter++` when it should be `y++`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `y <= maxRows` to `y < maxRows`. The highest index is 9 in an array of 10 elements. You will also need to change `counter++` to `y++` in order to increment `y`.

Also, `x` never changes, so you are only filling the first column with blanks. You should change `index < 2` to `x < 2` and `index++` to `x++`.

Finally, I suggest you learn about `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just made the specified changes

Comment: @amateurcoder1002 For future reference, please post real code that actual causes the error you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays#fill`

```
public class Untitled {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int maxRows = 10 ;
      String names[][] = new String[maxRows][2] ;
      for(String[] row : names){
          Arrays.fill(row, " ");
      }
   }
}
```